# How to tell grub.cfg to use isolinux.cfg menu

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, csm

I've built a custom iso based on Ubuntu 16.04 that boots in both UEFI and CSM (was originally CSM only). I'd like to have grub use the menu in isolinux.cfg. Is there a way to manage this or do I have to build a separate menu in grub.cfg? My isolinux.cfg follows:

```
PROMPT 0
TIMEOUT 75
DEFAULT menu.c32
F1 help.txt

MENU RESOLUTION 1024 768
MENU TABMSG [F1] help  [Tab] options 
# Dimensions configured for 

MENU TITLE Foxclone

LABEL standard
MENU DEFAULT
MENU LABEL Start ^Foxclone
  KERNEL /casper/vmlinuz
  APPEND boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz vga=791 quiet splash --
TEXT HELP
   If boot fails, reboot and try
   selecting Safe Mode instead
ENDTEXT

LABEL safe
MENU LABEL ^Safe Mode
  KERNEL /casper/vmlinuz
  APPEND boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz xforcevesa nomodeset vga=ask toram --
TEXT HELP
   Prompts for a video mode and
   loads the USB image into RAM
ENDTEXT

LABEL check
MENU LABEL ^Check USB for defects
  KERNEL /casper/vmlinuz
  APPEND boot=casper integrity-check initrd=/casper/initrd.lz splash --
TEXT HELP
   Verify integrity of USB drive
ENDTEXT

LABEL memtest
MENU LABEL ^Memory test
  KERNEL /install/memtest
  APPEND -
TEXT HELP
   Check computer memory for errors
ENDTEXT

menu color screen   37;40      #80ffffff #00000000 std
menu color border   30;44      #40000000 #00000000 std
menu color title    1;36;44    #c00090f0 #00000000 std
menu color unsel    37;44      #90ffffff #00000000 std
menu color hotkey   1;37;44    #ffffffff #00000000 std
menu color sel      7;37;40    #e0000000 #20ff8000 all
menu color hotsel   1;7;37;40  #e0400000 #20ff8000 all
menu color disabled 1;30;44    #60cccccc #00000000 std
menu color scrollbar    30;44      #40000000 #00000000 std
menu color tabmsg   31;40      #90ffff00 #00000000 std
menu color cmdmark  1;36;40    #c000ffff #00000000 std
menu color cmdline  37;40      #c0ffffff #00000000 std
menu color pwdborder    30;47      #80ffffff #20ffffff std
menu color pwdheader    31;47      #80ff8080 #20ffffff std
menu color pwdentry 30;47      #80ffffff #20ffffff std
menu color timeout_msg  37;40      #80ffffff #00000000 std
menu color timeout  1;37;40    #c0ffffff #00000000 std
menu color help     37;40      #c0ffffff #00000000 std
menu color msg07    37;40      #90ffffff #00000000 std
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is probably easiest to to have separate menus. An alternative is to boot via grub both in UEFI mode and BIOS mode (alias CSM). Then you can use the same menu. I do that in the persistent live systems created by [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). You can also see this link: ['Do it yourself'](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy).

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this custom iso is designed to run from the USB, not installed to a HD. I don't see how mkusb will help.

Comment: mkusb will not help when used, but it consists of bash shellscripts, and you can see (by looking at the `bash` code) how it is creating a boot system that works (from USB) via grub both in UEFI mode and BIOS mode. If you want to do that, I am willing to supply details (where to look, what to use etc).

Comment: I'd appreciate the guidance. I'm currently using xorriso to build the iso.

Comment: Must it be an iso file (bootable also from a DVD disk), or could it be an image to be bootable when cloned to a USB drive or memory card (or a tool, that creates such a bootable drive)?

Comment: I'm willing to investigate using an .img. I've never used an image file before but if it will run like running an iso from a USB and not increase the size of the download (~500Mb), I'm willing to try it. The main problem is the USB must boot itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104100/discussion-between-larry78723-and-sudodus).